# Как преобразовать дату в строку SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

Есть запись в формате DateTime `'2021-11-11 10:00:00'`
Как перевести ее в строку в следующем формате : `"11 ноября 2021"` ?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Указывайте точно используемую СУБД - в практически каждой эта операция выполняется по-своему (а в некоторых конвертация в локальный/национальный  формат вообще не предусмотрена - к тому же локаль сервера и клиента могут и не совпадать). Но гораздо разумнее выполнять это форматирование на клиентской стороне.